# How to wire and hang chandelier over table

Tags: lighting

I removed the electrical cap from ceiling, expecting to find capped, exposed wires like my other lights. However, I found 3 wires, 2 of them (white and orange) are not exposed and basically just run in one side of the box and out the other. What do I need to do to install a chandelier here? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Gods only know. Apparently those wires are already in use for some purpose, and the ceiling cap is currently just serving as a maintenance access for them. You need to figure out what they're powering, whether it's switched, where the switch is, how much power is already being used  (though using LED bulbs in the chandelier will keep it down to a minimal additional load)... All of which has to be done on site; we can't do it over the Internet. Not clear it isn't simpler to just have an electrician run a new circuit, or (cheap and cheerful) use a swag chain approach.

Comment: Pics. We need pics.